# rails to_xlsx Couldn't find all Vulnerabilities with 'id': (all, {}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I have an Rails app (ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.2.1). I would like to export data to excel using `acts_as_xlsx gem`.

Here is my controller:

```
class VulnerabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_vulnerability, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /vulnerabilities
  # GET /vulnerabilities.json
def index

  @vulnerabilities = Vulnerability.all 

  respond_to do | format |  
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @vulnerabilities }
  format.xlsx {
    send_data @vulnerabilities.to_xlsx.to_stream.read, :filename => 'costings.xlsx', :type => "application/vnd.openxmlformates-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  }
end
(…)
```

Here is my model:

```
class Vulnerability < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_xlsx
end
```

But when I click on my button:

```
<%= link_to 'Download', url_for(:format=>"xlsx") %>
```

I have an error:

```
Couldn't find all Vulnerabilities with 'id': (all, {}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Screenshot:

[image: ActiveRecord RecordNotFound]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I have the same issue after upgrading to Rails 4.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, after looking into the issue it appears that the default acts_as_xlsx gem is broken with rails 4.1+.  I found a repository that has a patch applied to the original acts_as_xlsx gem to resolve the issue, which can be found here:

https://github.com/straydogstudio/acts_as_xlsx

I updated my gem so that it pointed to the new repository

```
gem 'acts_as_xlsx',
  :git => "git://github.com/straydogstudio/acts_as_xlsx.git"
```

Alternatively you could download the zip and extract the folder into the vendor directory (renaming it from acts_as_xlsx-master to acts_as_xlsx).  Which is what I did just in case the patched repository disappears.

```
gem 'acts_as_xlsx',
  :path => "vendor/acts_as_xlsx"
```

Kudos to straydogstudio for the patch.